# Sprite size for a new UI in the constant physical size mode

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I want to provide the HD version for xxhdpi Android and other devices. Of course, I need to make all sprites with minimal size as it possible to show a graphics with any artefacts. So, I try to detect the preferred size for UI sprites.
My `Canvas` in the `constant physical size` mode.
So, should I follow to recommendations by Google?  I.e. `48 units (UI size units) = 144 pixels`. Or is it have some another recommended sizes?
**P.S.** Sorry, I'm noobie in Unity3D. Just I try to understand how I can calculate a preferred sprite pixel size for some UI size.